# Does recovering from knockdown bane prevents resisting other banes?

Tags: move-action, open-legend, banes

Knockdown description says:

> Standing up from prone requires a move action and costs a character half (round down) of their speed for the round.

While in [Combat Section](https://openlegendrpg.com/core-rules/07-combat) of the core rules it is described that one of the use of move action is to resist banes.

> You can use a move action to recover from one or more banes afflicting you. This move action cost is a simplified way of representing any number of different ways you might go about shaking off the wide range of banes you might be afflicted by. Roll 1d20 (with no attribute modifiers). If your roll is a 10 or higher, the bane is removed. *Note that some banes have different rules for how they can be resisted.*

Since knockdown specifically requires a move action to stand up, which means knockdown have different rules for how they can be resisted, **does this mean that the move action is used up only to recover from knockdown, and cannot be used to make a resist roll for all other banes?**

Comment: Another pertinent question: can one normally use a single move action to recover from multiple banes?  I don't know nearly enough about the system to give answers, but you seem to assume that one can, and that doesn't appear at all clear to me from the quote.

Comment: @BenBarden yes, normally a single move action can be used to resist all banes that allows it to be resisted this way. Some banes have special rule for resist, and knockdown is one of them

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.  The knockdown bane is instantaneous, and thus the "resist ends" rules do not apply to it.**

Looking at the [knockdown bane](https://openlegendrpg.com/banes/knockdown), the duration is listed as Instantaneous.  It has a persistent effect upon the world (you're prone) but that is not in and of itself a bane, it's just the state of being prone.  You'd have the same effect if you dropped to the floor voluntarily.  (For example, you might have wanted the +2 to Guard against ranged attacks, or perhaps you were tired and wanted to sleep.)

Resisting your current banes is a move action.  Standing up from prone is an entirely different move action.

On the bright side, standing up from prone doesn't require a die roll.